# Android Device Manager in Visual Studio 2017 shows 'Android SDK Platform is Missing'

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, sdk, android-emulator

I was able to open Android Device Manager in Visual Studio 2017, and use it to create or edit emulators. However, all of a sudden I'm getting the error '**Android SDK Platform is Missing**' while opening the same. Android SDK is set up correctly, I believe. I'm **able to run** the already created emulators. However I can't create a new device or edit existing devices due to the error I'm getting.

---

[image: The error message that appears on opening Device Manager]

*Img: The error message that appears on opening Device Manager*

---

[image: Android SDK Location is set correclty]

*Img: Android SDK Location is set correclty*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download by clicking on Tools -> Android -> Android SDK Manager
[image]

Secondly, select the API packages you require and click on Apply changes button.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Updating the SDK Platform helped me. Whoever finds an empty screen on opening the SDK Manager should click on the settings icon on the bottom right corner of the window and change the repository from `microsoft` to `google`.